# Most efficient way to index true/false values in C++

Tags: c++

I have a list of unsigned shorts that act as local IDs for a database. I was wondering what is the most memory-efficient way to store allowed IDs. For the lifetime of my project, the allowed ID list will be dynamic, so it may have more true or more false allowed IDs as time goes on, with a range of none allowed or all allowed.

What would be the best method to store these? I've considered the following:

1. List of allowed IDs
2. Bool vector/array of true/false for allowed IDs
3. Byte array that can be iterated through, similar to 2

Let me know which of these would be best or if another, better method, exists.

Thanks

EDIT: If possible, can a vector have a value put at say, index 1234, without all 1233 previous values, or would this suit a map or similar type more?
I'm looking at using an Arduino with 2k total ram and using external storage to assist with managing a large block of data, but I'm exploring what my options are

Comment: Since your IDs are of type `unsigned short` (a 16-bit data type), you are guaranteed that you will never have more than 65536 IDs at once; on a modern computer, that's not a huge number, so efficiency probably doesn't matter so much; any way you store them will be "fast enough".

Comment: That said, `std::unordered_map<unsigned short, bool>` has my vote, simply because it allows for quick lookups and iteration, and doesn't require any customize data-structure coding.

Comment: Why not a `std::set<unsigned short>` for only the `true` (allowed) IDs? If it's not in the set, it's not allowed?

Comment: What operations do you need to perform? Finding some free ID? Finding the smallest free ID?

Comment: Impossible to answer ... a std::bitset<65536> might be quickest but takes 8KB of memory. Unknown if that memory matters or not.

Comment: Your question already starts off confusing: first you want to store "allowed IDs", but then these IDs can have a "true" or "false" value. And then you come up with 3 solutions without any context. Where is it going to be used? Is speed important? Or memory footprint? Or maybe it doesn't actually matter, and you're doing micro optimizations. This is not a good question as it is

Comment: @DevSolar exactly. Imho I didn't misread. I think this is a XY problem or micro optimization. At least missing details: is performance important or not? Apart from the allowed id list, will the ID list change? Many details that matter for the answer

Answer (score 2):

"Best" is opinion-based, unless you are aiming for memory efficiency *at the expense of all other considerations*. Is that really what you want?

First of all, I hope we're talking `<vector>` here, not `<list>` -- because  a `std::list< short >` would be quite wasteful already.

What is the possible value range of those ID's? Do they use the full range of `0..USHRT_MAX`, or is there e.g. a high bit you could use to indicate allowed ones?

If that doesn't work, or you are willing to sacrifice a bit of space (no pun intended) for a somewhat cleaner implementation, go for a vector [partitioned](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partition) into allowed ones first, disallowed second. To check whether a given ID is allowed, `find` it in the vector and compare its position against the cut-off iterator (which you got from the partitioning). That would be the most memory-efficient standard container solution, and quite close to a memory-optimum solution either way. You would need to re-shuffle and update the cut-off iterator whenever the "allowedness" of an entry changes, though.

Comment: Yeah, by list I mean a vector, and the possible values would be from `0..USRT_MAX`, which if completely full would be very large, which is why I was looking for storing via bits.
I'll have a look into partitions, thanks.
I'm hoping to put it on an arduino with the help of external storage/progmem, but I want to explore my other options first

Comment: @AlexMH: *Generally* speaking, you should not attempt to optimize prematurely. Don't be *wasteful*, of course -- but unless you found your solution to have a resource / performance problem, use what comes naturally. You'll have to *look up* those IDs as well, and depending on how often you insert / delete / change an ID entry, optimizing for memory footprint *alone* might bite you in the performance department later on, so a `<set>` might be a valid choice as well.

Comment: @AlexMH On partitioned containers, it's simply a "true / false" sort so that you have all members of one group (valid IDs, in your case) together at the beginning and all members of the other group at the end. The return value is an iterator pointing to the first member of the second group. You'd need to keep that updated yourself, or re-run the partitioning, for each insert / removal / status change.

Comment: @Dev solar You answer a question and close it. This is slightly inconsistent

Comment: @ArminMontigny After writing the answer, comments changed my mind about the Q's quality.

Answer (score 1):

One suitable data structure to solve your problem is a trie (string tree) that holds your allowed or disallowed IDs.

Your can refer to the ID binary representation as the string. Trie is a compact way to store the IDs (memory wise) and the runtime access to it is bound by the longest ID length (which in your case is constant 16)

I'm not familiar with a standard library c++ implementation, but if efficiency is crucial you can find an implementation or implementat yourself.

Comment: `<map>` is usually implemented as a tree. But the question was specifically about memory efficiency, and trees are optimized for lookup speed, not memory footprint. You have a lot of pointers in there that are taking up space.

Comment: The data structure mentioned is a trie and not a tree, you might have pointers but you don't hold the full data of the ID, there's a tradeoff here.

Comment: There is a *lot* that could be argued for and against with various tradeoffs; as I said in my answer, that would end up being opinion-based and/or require more specific input from OP. If you are optimizing for memory footprint to the exclusion of everything else, a tree / trie is not optimal.